# How can I list all unique file names without their extensions in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a task where I need to move a bunch of files from one directory to another. I need move all files with the same file name (i.e. blah.pdf, blah.txt, blah.html, etc...) at the same time, and I can move a set of these every four minutes. I had a short bash script to just move a single file at a time at these intervals, but the new name requirement is throwing me off.
My old script is: 
 
`find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f | while read line; do mv "$line" ~/target_dir/; echo "$line"; sleep 240; done`

For the new script, I basically just need to replace  `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f`
with a list of unique file names without their extensions. I can then just replace `do mv "$line" ~/target_dir/;` with `do mv "$line*" ~/target_dir/;`.
So, with all of that said. What's a good way to get a unique list of files without their file names with bash script? I was thinking about using a regex to grab file names and then throwing them in a hash to get uniqueness, but I'm hoping there's an easier/better/quicker way. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A weird-named files tolerant one-liner could be:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -and -iname 'blah*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} ~/target/dir
```

If the files can start with multiple prefixes, you can use logic operators in find. For example, to move blah.* and foo.*, use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -and \( -iname 'blah.*' -or -iname 'foo.*' \) -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} ~/target/dir
```

#### EDIT

Updated after comment.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
find ./ -type f -printf '%f\n' | sed 's/\..*//' | sort | uniq | ( while read filename ; do find . -type f -iname "$filename"'*' -exec mv {} /dest/dir \; ; sleep 240; done )
```

Perhaps it needs some explaination:

- `find ./ -type f -printf '%f\n':` find all files and print just their name, followed by a newline. If you don't want to look in subdirectories, this can be substituted by a simple `ls`;
- `sed 's/\..*//'`: strip the file extension by removing everything after the first dot. Both `foo.tar` ad `foo.tar.gz` are transformed into `foo`;
- `sort | unique`: sort the filenames just found and remove duplicates;
- `(`: open a subshell:

  - `while read filename`: read a line and put it into the `$filename` variable;
  - `find . -type f -iname "$filename"'*' -exec mv {} /dest/dir \;`: find in the current directory (`find .`) all the files (`-type f`) whose name starts with the value in `filename` (`-iname "$filename"'*'`, this works also for files containing whitespaces in their name) and execute the `mv` command on each one (`-exec mv {} /dest/dir \;`)
  - `sleep 240`: sleep
- `)`: end of subshell.

Add `-maxdepth 1` as argument to `find` as you see fit for your requirements.

Comment: The filename won't always be 'blah*.' That was just an example. they won't be known or hard-coded at all. I need to get a list of all unique file names. So, for a folder that has the files "blah.html, blah.txt, foo.jpg, foo.html," it should output "blah, foo," which I could then pipe to a script that moves blah* and then foo* 4 minutes later. See what I mean?

Comment: I'd edit the answer with another one-liner, but you already answered your own question :)

Comment: Crud, actually, I just tried it, and it seems like <code>do mv $line*</code> doesn't actually work. Any ideas?

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope this is the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I'm dumb. there's a uniq command. Duh. New working script is: 
`find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f | sed -e 's/.[a-zA-Z]*$//' | uniq | while read line; do mv "$line*" ~/target_dir/; echo "$line"; sleep 240; done`

EDIT: Forgot close tag on code and a backslash.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to put the wildcard outside of the quotes (i.e. `mv "$line"* ...`) to get it to work.  Also, you should probably exclude dotfiles (i.e. add `-not -name ".*"` to the find command) to prevent it from finding ".somethingorother" -> "" -> `mv ""* ...` which would be bad.